Angular 15 update CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts
So, I upgrated Angular 14 up to 15. my package.json is
{
  "name": "tracker-web-dictionary",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "builddev": "ng build --configuration=dev",
    "builddemo": "ng build --configuration=demo",
    "buildstage": "ng build --configuration=stage",
    "buildmaster": "ng build --configuration=master",
    "buildprod": "ng build --configuration=prod",
    "buildcfo": "ng build --configuration=cfo",
    "builddtr": "ng build --configuration=dtr",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.10",
    "@ant-design/icons-angular": "^14.1.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "angular-notifier": "^11.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "messageformat": "^2.3.0",
    "ng-zorro-antd": "^14.1.1",
    "ngx-mask": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler": "^7.0.0",
    "ol": "^6.15.1",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primeng": "^14.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.5"
  }
}

after ng serve I got
Warning: C:\Users\Zendbook\Documents\DILAU\tracker-route-web-1\node_modules\geotiff\dist-module\geotiffimage.js depends on 'xml-utils/find-tags-by-name.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
Warning: C:\Users\Zendbook\Documents\DILAU\tracker-route-web-1\node_modules\geotiff\dist-module\geotiffimage.js depends on 'xml-utils/get-attribute.js'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
Warning: C:\Users\Zendbook\Documents\DILAU\tracker-route-web-1\node_modules\geotiff\dist-module\source\blockedsource.js depends on 'lru-cache'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
Warning: C:\Users\Zendbook\Documents\DILAU\tracker-route-web-1\node_modules\ol\layer\BaseVector.js depends on 'rbush'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
./node_modules/ol/ol.css?ngGlobalStyle:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

.ol-box {
|   box-sizing: border-box;
|   border-radius: 2px;

Failed to compile.
Could one advise what's wrong ?
I tried to re-install bootstrap a few times and I chaged my abgulr .json to add:
  "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [ "rxjs-compat" ],

I added @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css";
to style.css
and it works!
